# Digamma function in Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to produce a 3d plot of the following function in latex using tikz:
[image]

where psi(a) is the digamma function, I'm not really sure how I can write this function in latex code? or if it already exists
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function for reference

Comment: Is calling an external program an acceptable solution to you? Or should the solution be tikz only?

Comment: @1010011010 i don't mind, I actually just realised I can do that so I am trying to solve it that way, seems easier than doing it in tikz if the function doesn't already exist or hasn't been written up before

Comment: You could write a little luatex routine.....

Comment: @JPi sorry not familiar with that term?

Comment: Luatex is an engine that allows you to program bits in the lua programming language.  It's the designated successor to pdftex.  Worth looking into in general, albeit not if you'd only be using it for this problem.